# Is there a convenient tool for drawing (dialect) maps?

Tags: reference-request, dialects, dialect-mapping

I need to draw a dialect map, splitting an area up into differently coloured regions. Is there an online tool for creating dialect maps?
Of course, any map drawing tool where I can take an existing map and draw lines, shade areas, label etc. would work fine

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892267/andy-ideas-of-where-i-can-find-good-svg-maps and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320952/how-to-automatically-create-imagemaps-of-grey-maps-from-wikipedia. Use your favorite SVG editor to fill them in.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of a specific tool for making dialect maps but it does sound like something suitable for [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.com/) (OSM) and its many map-making tools.

Egotistically, it would be a great overlay to put on top of another map on my GPS, which uses OSM =) It would make for some silly trips: *Are we at the isogloss yet? This is retroflex /l/-country!*

Comment: Actually... idea for website: database-backed, for school children to learn about language and dialects by answering questions about their own speech, being used to build a map with isoglosses...

Answer (score 1):

[This question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320952/how-to-automatically-create-imagemaps-of-grey-maps-from-wikipedia) has information on where one can find blank maps to fill in. It turns out that Wikipedia has [quite a few template maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Blank_maps).

There are [several tutorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Graphics_Lab/Resources/Tutorials) too on Wikipedia on how you can go about modifying them. In particular, the articles titled "Change the colors of a country", "Create and color map zones", and "Cut a map into several sub-areas". The last two of these are in French, but the Google Translated versions of these are quite readable too. Also, read [this introduction to cartography with Inkscape](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/Tutorial-cartography_%28basic%29.svg).

These articles recommend using the software, [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/).